# IntelliJ Plugin - 'sonar.projectDate' property cannot be older than the date of the last known quality snapshot on this project

Tags: sonarqube

I get the following error when running the SonarQube IntelliJ Analysis Plugin

```
14:40:35.544 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
   at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
   at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
   at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
   at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.execute(BatchLauncherMain.java:41)
   at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncherMain.main(BatchLauncherMain.java:59)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sonar.projectDate' property cannot be older than the date of the last known quality snapshot on this project. Value: '2014-01-23T14:40:35-0700'. Latest quality snapshot: '2014-01-23'. This property may only be used to rebuild the past in a chronological order.
at
org.sonar.batch.ProjectConfigurator.checkCurrentAnalysisIsTheLatestOne(ProjectConfigurator.java:87)
   at org.sonar.batch.ProjectConfigurator.configure(ProjectConfigurator.java:71)
   at org.sonar.batch.DefaultProjectTree.doStart(DefaultProjectTree.java:72)
   at org.sonar.batch.DefaultProjectTree.start(DefaultProjectTree.java:49)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

This thread discusses a similar issue with Eclipse and SonarQube - http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.sonar.general/31498 . But the thread hasn't been helpful.

I am running IntelliJ 13 and The SonarQube Plugin for IntelliJ v 1.0.

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling the plugin. And I have tried clearing the "User cache". I am not sure what to try next.

The sonar project is part of the CI chain - so there are potentially multiple builds per day on the project.

Thanks

Comment: The underlying error is **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sonar.projectDate' property cannot be older than the date of the last known quality snapshot on this project. Value: '2014-01-23T14:40:35-0700'. Latest quality snapshot: '2014-01-23'. This property may only be used to rebuild the past in a chronological order.**

Answer (score 6):

If you are running builds both locally and from a CI server, check that the clocks are relatively the same between the machines.  If your CI server is ahead of your local machine, and publishing to Sonar (on check-in for example), but then you are also running locally with a different time (that's in the past) and trying to publish to sonar, then that could be a possible source of the conflict.

Comment: The problem is related to the fact that the Sonar server is running in a different timezone than the IntelliJ instance. At least that is what it seems to be - https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5049. Thanks...

Comment: I think this is my problem too. The error is horrendous, it should show the time of the latest quality snapshot, as it stands it suggests you cant make a build until tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this is a bug in the 4.1 version of Sonar

https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5049.

Comment: Are you doing this analysis from eclipse?

Comment: No. I was performing the analysis from IntelliJ.

Comment: For eclipse, I just advanced my local system time to a date higher than the last snapshot date. See if you can do the same in your case.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 possible workarounds:

- Set your machine to the same timezone as your sonar server

or

- Go to Eclipse preferences, SonarQube, Preview Analysis Properties, add a property called `sonar.projectDate` with a date in the future like `2024-01-01`.
  (from https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5049). Your local date will then always be ahead of the server's date, as far as the local analysis engine is concerned.